# Injective objects in the category of non-negative cochain complex

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, homology-cohomology, simplicial-complex

I am reading a notes of Brian Conrad on hypercovering, and in the discussion on Dold-Kan correspondence, it is claimed (I might misunderstand) that the injective objects in the category of non-negative cochain complexes ($\mathcal{CoChain}_{\ge 0}(Ab)$) are exactly those complex $I^\bullet$, such that all the $I^j$ is injective (in $Ab$), and the positive cohomology vanishes.

Here is the link of the notes: [https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/hypercover.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjHz8rVorP0AhVoR_EDHUeJAk8QFnoECAMQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0NKji5VcAbACZX2hMZlXek](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://math.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/papers/hypercover.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjHz8rVorP0AhVoR_EDHUeJAk8QFnoECAMQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0NKji5VcAbACZX2hMZlXek).
The claim appears on page 12, in the first paragraph of the proof of Cor.2.13.

Although I can see the two conditions here are necessary, and I do not know why these are sufficient conditions. In particular, if I take an object in $Ab$, and take its injective resolution, I do not think the resolution is injective.
So my question is whether there is a good characterization of injective objects in this category. Should I expect there to be some simple answer? Any comment is sincerely welcome.

Comment: 1. There are at least two notable Conrads. It would help if you said which one and provided a link to the notes in the post. 2. Of course the resolution of some object $A$ isn't injective if the object is nonzero - it has first cohomology $A$! There are lots of good criteria for injectivity of an object in an abelian category - have you tried to verify that an acyclic complex of injective objects satisfies any of them? If not, that's the first thing to do. If you try and get stuck, please [edit] that in to your post.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I will edit the question

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I have found the answer myself. The answer should be that one need to add one more condition, that is, $H^0(I^\bullet)$ is also injective.

First, to see why this condition is necessary, we take $A^\bullet=A[0]$ and $B^\bullet=B[0]$ with $A\hookrightarrow B$, then $$Hom(A^\bullet, I^\bullet)=Hom(A,H^0(I^\bullet))$$
Therefore, $H^0(I^\bullet)$ should also be injective.

Now given such a complex, from the process above, we see it will not harm as to add in $H^0(I^\bullet)$ as the (-1)-th term. So without loss of generality, we simply assume that $I^\bullet$ has $H^i$ vanish for all $i\ge0$. Then we have the standard process of breaking the long exact sequence into short ones, and moreover since the sequence consists of injectives, each of these short exact sequences actually split. Then a basic diagram chasing gives the result.

Comment: This is wrong - if $B^\bullet = B[0]$, then $H^0(B^\bullet)=B$, so the condition is trivially satisfied by the assumption that $B$ is injective. You can show directly that any complex satisfying Conrad's listed conditions obeys the defining property of an injective object: given $X^\bullet\to Y^\bullet$ an injection and $X^\bullet \to I^\bullet$ any map, you can define a map $Y^\bullet \to I^\bullet$ which extends $X^\bullet\to I^\bullet$ by induction and diagram chasing. This is a standard first exercise in homological algebra and I'd recommend you do it.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not quite understand which point you are objecting. Do you mean that $H^0(I^\bullet)$ should be automatically be injective? I think the typical non-example is to take an object $M$ that is not injective itself, and then take $I^\bullet$ to be its injective resolution. Then there will be an obstruction of extension that comes from $H^0(I^\bullet)=M$. I must have misunderstood your explanation, and I would really appreciate your clarification.

Comment: No, I'm saying that your toy example is too much of a toy and doesn't give accurate expectations for the whole problem. You really should do the exercise mentioned in the first comment above.

Comment: If you would excuse my stupidity, I am still confused, because I have definitely done the exercise already, as this is just the statement that Conrad has made. It is during doing this exercise that I realized that $H^0$ will cause a problem. It might seem that one can extend $A^0\to I^0$ arbitrarily to $B^0\to I^0$, but after inspection, one finds that $A^1\to I^1$ is involved unavoidably. If I remember homology algebra well enough, there is a lemma about one can lift maps between $M\to N$ to a map between there resolutions, but I can agree this is still true without a given $M\to N$.

Comment: (Sorry, it should be "I can't agree with this" in the last sentence of my last  comment)